# Service created using bindService is not unbounded nor destroyed when the activity is destroyed

Tags: android, service

I start my service using bindService only(not the startService). 
But when i destroy the activity, it is not calling onUnbind method or onDestroy method of the service class. But when i start it using both bindService and startService, onUnbind is  called and onDestroy is also called if i stop it. 
I expect onUnbind to be called when i destroy the activity in the first case because when bindService is used, then it should unBind it when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: of course you are calling `unbindService(ServiceConnection conn)` in your `Activity`?

Comment: no i am not. I tried calling it explicitly and it worked fine then. But from what i read, whenever the activity is destroyed the service is unBounded and it should call onUnbind method.

Comment: where did you read it?  in official googke docs or in some web tutorials?

Comment: When i start the service using both bindService as well as startService and when i destroy the app, the unBind is called. But it is not the same when i call only bindService. Why is it calling unBind only when i use both the function calls?

Comment: what is `unBind` ? you mean `unbindService` ? when / where do you call it? also what does it mean: `when i destroy the app`?

Comment: Ok let me be clear. I know there is a method called unBindService which i can call to unBind the service and whenever i do that the method onUnbind method i called which i think you know pretty well. So coming to the point. Destroy the app means closing the app that calls the method onDestroy. I never call the method unBindService. The system calls it when i destroy the app only when i use bindService and startService to start the service. When i use only bindService, and try to destroy the activity,the system is not calling it.

Comment: so if you are calling `bindService` then always call `unbindService`, more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding)

Comment: `'''But when i destroy the activity, it is not calling onUnbind method or onDestroy method of the service class.'''` no, this is not true, tested on 4.4, 5.0 and 6.0

Comment: So you mean that when the activity is destroyed(closed), then onUnbind is callled ie, the service is unbounded automatically without we callling unBindService()?

Comment: By the way,Thanks for helping.

Comment: yes, in *guide/components/bound-services.html* i have found the following: `When your client is destroyed, it will unbind from the service, but you should always unbind when you're done interacting with the service or when your activity pauses so that the service can shutdown while its not being used. (Appropriate times to bind and unbind is discussed more below.)` the same should be mentioned in **Context#bindService** / **Context#unbindService** docs